# RecyclerView not showing anything even after receiving data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, rx-java2, android-room, android-mvp

I am trying to populate some data on a `RecyclerView`. The data is obtained in one of the ways:

1. Request data from an API if internet is present (using `Retrofit` and `RxJava2`), persist the data to local database (using `Room`), send the data to the `View` (in my case it is a `Fragment`).
2. If no internet then get data from the local database and send it to the `View`.

**I'm using MVP as the application architecture and I'm using `ViewModels` to deal with the data handling for the UI. I am using `ButterKnife` to do the view finding.**

The `Presenter` calls the `Repository`, which gets the data based on the conditions specified above and then the data is sent to the `Views` by the `Presenter` where the `ViewModel` intercepts the data and does the necessary steps to pass the data to the UI elements (the `RecyclerView` adapter update).

My problem is:

1. Even when I see in the debugger that the data is reaching to `RecyclerViewAdapter`, the screen is blank. No data is shown.
2. The result from the local database throws `IllegalStateException`, saying that local db cannot be accessed from the main thread, even when I `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` when I'm calling the function to return the data from local db, which return a `Maybe<>`.

My code is as follows:
The repository:

```
public class CountriesListApiRepository {
    private final IRestServiceDataFetcher restServiceDataFetcher; // Retrofit interface to get data from API

    @Inject
    public CountriesListApiRepository(IRestServiceDataFetcher restServiceDataFetcher) {
        this.restServiceDataFetcher = restServiceDataFetcher;
    }

    public Maybe<List<CountriesFullEntity>> getCountriesFromApi() {
        return restServiceDataFetcher
                .getListOfCountriesData()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }
}
```

---

```
public class CountriesListLocalDbRepository {
    private final CountriesLocalDb countriesLocalDb;

    @Inject
    CountriesListLocalDbRepository(CountriesLocalDb countriesLocalDb) {
        this.countriesLocalDb = countriesLocalDb;
    }

    Maybe<List<CountriesFullEntity>> getCountriesFromLocalDb() {
        return this.countriesLocalDb
                .getCountriesLocalDbDAO()
                .getCountriesList()
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }

    void updateLocalDb(List<CountriesFullEntity> updatedCountriesList) {
        countriesLocalDb.getCountriesLocalDbDAO().insertAllCountries(updatedCountriesList);

    }
}
```

---

```
public class CountriesListRepository {
    private final CountriesListApiRepository countriesListApiRepository;
    private final CountriesListLocalDbRepository countriesListLocalDbRepository;
    private static final String TAG_CountriesListRepository = "CountriesListRepository";

    @Inject
    public CountriesListRepository(CountriesListApiRepository countriesListApiRepository,
                                   CountriesListLocalDbRepository countriesListLocalDbRepository) {
        this.countriesListApiRepository = countriesListApiRepository;
        this.countriesListLocalDbRepository = countriesListLocalDbRepository;
    }

    public Maybe<List<CountriesFullEntity>> getCountries() {
        return this.countriesListApiRepository
                .getCountriesFromApi()
                .doOnSuccess(this.countriesListLocalDbRepository::updateLocalDb)
                .doOnError(throwable -> {
                    Log.d(TAG_CountriesListRepository,throwable.getMessage());
                    throwable.printStackTrace(); })
                .onErrorResumeNext(this.countriesListLocalDbRepository.getCountriesFromLocalDb());
    }
}
```

---

---

My Presenter:

```
public class BasePresenter<T extends BaseView> {
    @Inject
    T injectedView;

    private static final String TAG_BASE_PRESENTER = "BasePresenter";

    T getInjectedView() {
        return injectedView;
    }

    <V> void subscribeToObserver(Maybe<V> flowable, MaybeObserver<V> maybeObserver) {
        flowable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnSubscribe(subscription -> Log.d(TAG_BASE_PRESENTER,"Subscribed"))
                .doOnSuccess(v -> Log.d(TAG_BASE_PRESENTER,"onNext() completed"))
                .subscribe(maybeObserver);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class CountriesListPresenter extends BasePresenter<CountriesListView>
        implements MaybeObserver<List<CountriesFullEntity>> {

    private static final String TAG_ListPresenter = "CountriesListPresenter";

    private final CountriesListRepository countriesListRepository;

    private Disposable disposable;

    @Inject
    public CountriesListPresenter(CountriesListRepository countriesListRepository) {
        this.countriesListRepository = countriesListRepository;
    }

    public void getCountries() {
        Maybe<List<CountriesFullEntity>> listOfCountriesData = this.countriesListRepository
                .getCountries();
        subscribeToObserver(listOfCountriesData, this);
    }

    public void updateCountriesList(@NonNull Boolean isInternetThere) {
        Maybe<List<CountriesFullEntity>> newCountriesFullData = this.countriesListRepository
                .updateCountriesList(isInternetThere);
        subscribeToObserver(newCountriesFullData,this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
        this.disposable = d;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<CountriesFullEntity> countriesFullEntities) {
        Log.d(TAG_ListPresenter,"Executing onNext()");
        getInjectedView().onLoadCountriesDataFull(countriesFullEntities);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Log.d(TAG_ListPresenter,"Executing onError()",e);
        getInjectedView().onErrorEncountered(e.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        if(!disposable.isDisposed()) disposable.dispose();
    }
}
```

---

---

My Views:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IFragmentToFragmentMediator, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    public static final String TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY = "MainActivity";

    public static final String TAG_LIST_FRAGMENT = "COUNTRY_LIST";
    public static final String TAG_DETAILS_FRAGMENT = "COUNTRY_DETAILS";

    @BindView(R.id.MainActSwipeRefreshLayout)
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    private Unbinder unbinder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
        Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY,"Main Activity View Created");
        if(config.smallestScreenWidthDp<600){
            CountriesListFrag countriesListFrag = new CountriesListFrag();
            conductFragmentTransaction(countriesListFrag,TAG_LIST_FRAGMENT, false, true);
            Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY,"Main Activity < 600 and portrait");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
            Fragment f = fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_DETAILS_FRAGMENT);
            if (f instanceof  CountryDetailsFrag) fm.popBackStack();
            else this.finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        // TODO : Code the refreshing data callback here
        Fragment countryListFragment = returnNonNullRunningFragmentByTagName(TAG_LIST_FRAGMENT);
        Fragment countryDetailsFragment = returnNonNullRunningFragmentByTagName(TAG_DETAILS_FRAGMENT);
        makeViewsSignalUpdateOfData((CountriesListFrag)countryListFragment);
        makeViewsSignalUpdateOfData((CountryDetailsFrag)countryDetailsFragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void invokeDetailsFragmentOnListItemCLickedInListFragment(CountriesFullEntity countriesFullEntity) {
        CountryDetailsFrag countryDetailsFrag = CountryDetailsFrag.newInstance();
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putSerializable("data",countriesFullEntity);
        countryDetailsFrag.setArguments(data);
        conductFragmentTransaction(countryDetailsFrag, TAG_DETAILS_FRAGMENT, false, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void invokeDetailsFragmentOnListItemClickedInListFragmentViewModel() {

        CountryDetailsFrag countryDetailsFrag =
                (CountryDetailsFrag) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_DETAILS_FRAGMENT);

        if(countryDetailsFrag!=null && countryDetailsFrag.isVisible())
        conductFragmentTransaction(countryDetailsFrag, TAG_DETAILS_FRAGMENT, true, true);
    }

    private void makeViewsSignalUpdateOfData(BaseView view) {
        if(view != null) view.onPerformUpdateAction();
    }

    private Fragment returnNonNullRunningFragmentByTagName(String tagName) {
        Fragment fragmentForProcessing = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tagName);
        if(fragmentForProcessing!=null && fragmentForProcessing.isVisible()) return fragmentForProcessing;
        return null;
    }

    private void conductFragmentTransaction(Fragment targetFragment, String tag, boolean addOrReplaceFlag, boolean backStackFlag) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if(addOrReplaceFlag)fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentCanvas,targetFragment,tag);
        else fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentCanvas,targetFragment,tag);
        if(backStackFlag)fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unbinder.unbind();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class CountriesListFrag extends Fragment implements CountriesListView {

    public static final String TAG_LIST_FRAGMENT = "ListFragment";

    @Inject
    Picasso picasso;
    @Inject
    CountriesListPresenter countriesListPresenter;

    private IFragmentToFragmentMediator listeningActivity;
    private Frag2FragCommViewModel frag2FragCommViewModel;

    @BindView(R.id.CountriesEntireHolderRV)
    RecyclerView countriesEntireHolderRV;
    private CountriesListRecyclerViewAdapter countriesListRecyclerViewAdapter;
    private Unbinder unbinder;

    public CountriesListFrag() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        DaggerCountryComponents
                .builder()
                .appComponents(((CentralApplication)context.getApplicationContext())
                        .getAppComponents())
                .countryModule(new CountryModule(this))
                .build()
                .inject(this);
        super.onAttach(context);
        try{
            this.listeningActivity = (MainActivity) context;

            this.frag2FragCommViewModel = ViewModelProviders
                    .of((MainActivity) context)
                    .get(Frag2FragCommViewModel.class);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement IFragmentToFragmentMediator");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_countries_list, container, false);
        if(v!=null) this.unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this,v);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        initialize();
        this.countriesListPresenter.getCountries();
        setUpListItemClickListener();

        frag2FragCommViewModel
                .getLiveDataListOfCountriesData()
                .observe(this,countriesFullEntities ->
                        countriesListRecyclerViewAdapter.setCountriesFullEntityList(countriesFullEntities));
        Log.d(TAG_LIST_FRAGMENT,"List Fragment View Created");

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadCountriesDataFull(List<CountriesFullEntity> countriesFullData) {
//        this.countriesListRecyclerViewAdapter.setCountriesFullEntityList(countriesFullData);
        Log.d(TAG_LIST_FRAGMENT,"Data Received in List Fragment");
        Log.d(TAG_LIST_FRAGMENT,countriesFullData.get(0).getName());
        this.frag2FragCommViewModel.setListOfCountriesData(countriesFullData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorEncountered(String errorMessage) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), errorMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPerformUpdateAction() {
        callToPresenterToUpdateListOfCountriesOnInternetPresent(this.getContext());
    }

    private void initialize() {
        this.countriesEntireHolderRV = new RecyclerView(this.getContext());
        this.countriesListRecyclerViewAdapter = new CountriesListRecyclerViewAdapter(new ArrayList<>(),
                LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext()), this.picasso);

        this.countriesEntireHolderRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));
        this.countriesEntireHolderRV
                .addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this.countriesEntireHolderRV.getContext()
                        ,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        this.countriesEntireHolderRV.setAdapter(this.countriesListRecyclerViewAdapter);
        Log.d(TAG_LIST_FRAGMENT,"List Fragment init");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        this.unbinder.unbind();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class CountriesListRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CountriesListRecyclerViewAdapter.CountriesListViewHolder>{
    private List<CountriesFullEntity> countriesFullEntityList;
    private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private final Picasso picasso;
    private CountriesListRVClickListener countriesListRVClickListener;
    private int currentPosition;

    CountriesListRecyclerViewAdapter(List<CountriesFullEntity> countriesFullEntityList, LayoutInflater layoutInflater, Picasso picasso) {
        this.countriesFullEntityList = countriesFullEntityList;
        this.layoutInflater = layoutInflater;
        this.picasso = picasso;
        this.currentPosition = 0;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CountriesListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new CountriesListViewHolder(this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.countries_list_layout,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CountriesListViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CountriesFullEntity countriesFullEntity = countriesFullEntityList.get(position);
        picasso.load(countriesFullEntity.getFlag()).into(holder.countryIcon);
        holder.nameOfCountry.setText(countriesFullEntity.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.countriesFullEntityList.size();
    }

    void setItemClickListener(CountriesListRVClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.countriesListRVClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    CountriesFullEntity getCountriesFullEntityAtPosition(int position) {
        return this.countriesFullEntityList.get(position);
    }

    void setCountriesFullEntityList(List<CountriesFullEntity> countriesFullEntityList) {
        this.countriesFullEntityList = countriesFullEntityList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    int getCurrentPosition() {
        return currentPosition;
    }

    void setCurrentPosition(int currentPosition) {
        this.currentPosition = currentPosition;
    }

    class CountriesListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        @BindView(R.id.NameOfCountry)
        TextView nameOfCountry;
        @BindView(R.id.CountryIcon)
        ImageView countryIcon;
        CountriesListViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            countriesListRVClickListener.onListItemClicked(v,getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

---

---

My DAOs:

```
@Dao
public interface CountriesLocalDbDAO {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Countries")
    Maybe<List<CountriesFullEntity>> getCountriesList();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Countries WHERE name LIKE :countryName")
    Maybe<CountriesFullEntity> getCountryByName(String countryName);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertAllCountries(List<CountriesFullEntity> countryList);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertSingleCountry(CountriesFullEntity singleCountry);

    @Delete
    void deleteSingleCountry(CountriesFullEntity singleCountry);

    @Delete
    void endOfTheWorld(List<CountriesFullEntity> theWorld);
}
```

---

```
public interface IRestServiceDataFetcher {
    @GET("all")
    Maybe<List<CountriesFullEntity>> getListOfCountriesData();
    @GET("name/{name}")
    Maybe<CountriesFullEntity> getParticularCountry(@Path("name") String name);
}
```

---

---

My layouts:

ActivityMainLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/fragmentCanvas"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/MainActSwipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

FragmentListLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.countrieslist.CountriesListFrag">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/CountriesEntireHolderRV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerViewViewHolderLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/CountryIcon"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/NameOfCountry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/CountryIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

---

My app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "shankhadeepghoshal.org.countrieslistapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        //noinspection OldTargetApi
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath = true
            }
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++14 -frtti -fexceptions"
            }
        }
        // multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.16'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.16'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.16'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.16'

    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    implementation(
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.9.6'],
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.6'],
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.9.6']
    )

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-java8:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2'

    def room_version = "1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$room_version"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:guava:$room_version"
    testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$room_version"

    def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:$lifecycle_version"
    testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

UPDATE:

I did what @Ben-P suggested in his answer. But now my RecycleViewAdapter is giving me errors.
I am getting an `IllegalArgumentException - Target must be null` on this line : `picasso.load(countriesFullEntity.getFlag()).into(holder.countryIcon);` in `onBindViewHolder(holder,position)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fragment, you have this code:

> ```
> private void initialize() {
>     this.countriesEntireHolderRV = new RecyclerView(this.getContext());
>     ...
> }
> ```

Earlier, in `onCreateView()`, you call `ButterKnife.bind()`... which means that the above code is reassigning `countriesEntireHolderRV` to a new reference. This new RecyclerView is never added to your Fragment's view (and probably wouldn't be visible anyway, since the LinearLayout already has a child taking up all the visible space), so all of your operations work with a RecyclerView that the user can't see.

Just delete that line from `initialize()`. Then you'll be working with the RecyclerView in your layout file, and everything should appear.

Comment: I am using `ButterKnife` to do the find views.

Comment: @ShankhadeepGhoshal wow, sorry about that. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Well, I'm new to the Jake Warthon Stack. Pretty petty mistake. Also, why is the Rx acting up? I mean, in `CountriesListRepository.getCountries()`, when I call the `localDb.update()`, I get an `IllegalStateException` which tell me not to perform network updates on the main thread. But in the `localDbRepository.getCountriesFromLocalDb()`, I `scheduleOn(io())`.

Comment: I'm not sure about the answer to that. I think you'd probably be better served opening a second question about that, and narrowing down the code you include.

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna do that now. But now Picasso is acting up. Thank you.